# ListView_MouseLeave() not firing when mouse left button is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mouseevent

I am trying to drag elements from my WPF application's ListView to Windows Explorer using this code:

```
private void ListView1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     Hide();                               //Breakpoint here
     Point mpos = e.GetPosition(null);
     Vector diff = this.start - mpos;

     ....rest of the code
```

But when I put the breakpoint at `Hide();`, which hides the form when drag starts, and start dragging out of `ListView1`, control doesn't reaches at that breakpoint. But when I release the left mouse button, it successfully reaches at that breakpoint. Can you please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the standard WPF drag/drop events? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742859%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @DrewNoakes I used `DragLeave` but it was not working. Control was unable to reach `Hide()` when I used `DragLeave` in place of `MouseLeave`.

Comment: Lacking [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to provide a solution to said problem. That said, it's possible the mouse has been captured by the dragging operation and so no `MouseLeave` event is generated until the drag has completed and capturing is ended.